# Uploading an audio file and receiving unexpected response in ios

Tags: ios, audio, upload, nsurlconnection

Here it is my code to `upload an audio file`. `I tried lot of questions and answers in stackoverflow`. But still i am not getting any improvement on this. I have to upload an audio file with a `php link`. If i do that, i am getting response like "`already exists`" always. I tried to change the filename and upload it. still getting same response. Actually i have to receive a response from the server as link of a file i uploaded. I am not having any knowledge about `php`. Anyone help me with this. Any help would be appreciated to clear my issue.

```
   NSData *fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://somesite.com/upload.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"fvgv4r346r4r4h3ur543ty5u54y5u4574545g4g5.samr\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[soundFileURL lastPathComponent]
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: music/samr\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:fileData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[body bytes]]);

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: music/samr\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

I suspect this line

Also check your input variable